# Highcharts: options setting for customized renderer

Tags: highcharts

I am using Highcharts to draw some complex figures.

I use it like:

```
var renderer = new Highcharts.Renderer(
            $('#container')[0], 400, 400
        );
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    plotItem(renderer, data[i]);
}
```

A simplified case is [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B4frF/1/).

Now how to set the options of the chart? Say, I want to have the default 'export' menu, set the chart title, etc.

Meanwhile, I would like to add customized tooltip to the shape of every item. Something like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/72xym/4/). How to add it?

I somehow cannot 'hook' the `Highcharts.Renderer` to `Highcharts.Chart`...

---

UPDATE:

After searching, I connect the Chart and Renderer objects by [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/B4frF/6/). But how to add customized tooltips to the rectangle (currently I put alert)?

Comment: Here is Highchart API can help you for features http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything in the API that allows you to "turn on" the tooltip for `Renderer` created objects.  In the link you provided, they create points close to the `Renderer` objects, and then the `mouseover` of the object passes that point.

You can follow that pattern (mapping points to the `Renderer` objects):

```
function some(renderer) {
    renderer.rect(10, 10, 100, 100, 1).attr({
        fill: 'red'
     }).add().on('mouseover', function () {
                var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
                var point = chart.series[0].points[0];
                chart.tooltip.refresh(point);
        })
            .on('mouseout', function () {
                var chart = Highcharts.charts[0];
                chart.tooltip.hide();
        });
}
```

See fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B4frF/8/).

Or you could manipulate the tooltip even more directly:

```
function some(renderer) {
    renderer.rect(10, 10, 100, 100, 1).attr({
        fill: 'red'
    }).add().on('mousemove', function(e) {    
        Highcharts.charts[0].tooltip.move(e.pageX,e.pageY); // follow the mouse       
    }).on('mouseout', function(e) {
        Highcharts.charts[0].tooltip.hide(); // off the rect, hide it
    }).on('mouseover', function(e) {
        var tooltip = Highcharts.charts[0].tooltip;
        clearTimeout(tooltip.hideTimer); // if it was in the process of hiding, cancel
        tooltip.isHidden = false; // mark it as shown
        tooltip.label.attr({
                text: 'Hi Mom!' // add a label
        });
        tooltip.label.attr('opacity', 1).show(); // show it
    });
}
```

See updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B4frF/7/).